# Pygame on Alpine Docker image?

Tags: python, docker, pygame

I'm trygin to install a Django project on Docker, for testing purposes, but while i got the installation of the Pygame library, it launches an error(Many actually) saying that no Pygame version is available to install, from 2.0.1 to 1.9.2, and in some way, all of them show an error similar to `/bin/sh: sdl2-config: not found`. I tried searching, and it seems i need an SDL2 package for it to work. Alpine has a SDL2 package, tried to install it, but didn't work, searching a little more found that maybe i need a more specific one called python:pygame-sdl2, but the only thing i found respecting Alpine was this Google result:

[image: Result]

It mentions that the package is absent on Alpine, but i can't find that same line if i make click on the result link.

Does anyone knows if it's possible install a Pygame project on an Alpine Image, or which would be the next recommendable image to mount a Django project?

This is my Dockerfile, just in case:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine as base

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    ca-certificates gcc postgresql-dev linux-headers musl-dev libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev geos sdl2\ 
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM base as debug

RUN pip3 install debugpy
```

Comment: [Searching pkgs.alpinelinux.org](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=sdl2-config&path=&name=&branch=v3.8&arch=x86_64) finds an [sdl2-dev package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.8/main/x86_64/sdl2-dev); is that what you need?

Comment: @DavidMaze At first seems like that was for the SDL2 dependency, but it's launching more dependencies errors, not sure if they are related to the SDL2 package. Will check a little more.

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidMaze mentioned, the package sdl2-dev is the one required, there are 2 versions of packages, the normal ones and the -devs, and seems that python libraries require the latest ones, reason as why didn't work when i installed the sdl2. After this i only had to deal with a few other packages missing(The worst one was portmidi, since it was on the Edge branch), but after all that, the library has already been compiled.